# Не работает маска для поля Дата рождения

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

```
<?php
    include("db_connect.php"); 
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    if (isset($_POST["add"])) {
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `message` (`name`, `surname`, `patronymic`, `date`, `text`) 
                            VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['surname']."','".$_POST['patronymic']."','".$_POST['date']."','".$_POST['text']."')");
    }

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap Template</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Martel|Rubik" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.js"></script>

      </head>
    <body>

      <header>
      <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <form action="index.php" method="POST" class="col-lg-6" role="form">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="surname">Фамилия</label>
      <input type="name" class="form-control qwerty" name="surname" id="surname">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Имя</label>
      <input type="name" class="form-control qwerty" name="name" id="name">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="patronymic">Отчетсво</label>
      <input type="name" class="form-control qwerty" name="patronymic" id="patronymic">
     </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="date">Дата рождения</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control qwerty" name="date" id="date">
      <script>
    $(function() {
      //задание заполнителя с помощью параметра placeholder
      $("#date").mask("99.99.9999", {placeholder: "20.12.2000" });
    });
    </script>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text">Биография</label>
      <textarea name="text" class="form-control" rows="7" id="text"></textarea>
    </div>
     <button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary">Добавить</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col-md-1">ID</th>
          <th class="col-md-3" >Дата рождения</th>
          <th class="col-md-2">Фамилия</th>
          <th class="col-md-2">Имя</th>
          <th class="col-md-2">Отчество</th>
          <th class="col-md-2">Биография</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>


    <?php 
    $result=mysql_query(
        "SELECT id,DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%d.%m.%Y') as `date`,surname,name,patronymic,text FROM message"
    ); 

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))


    { // выводим данные

    echo "<tr>\n\t<td>".$row["id"]."</td>"."\n\t"."<td>"."".$row["date"]."

    </td>"."\n\t"."<td>"."".$row["surname"]."</td>"."\n\t"."<td>"."".$row
    ["name"]."</td>"."\n\t"."<td>"."".$row["patronymic"]."</td>"."\n\t"."<td>
    "."".$row["text"]."</td>"."\n\t"."</tr>"."\n";
    }

    mysql_close();

    ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>
    </header>

        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Сейчас стоит дд.мм.гггг а нужно либо любую дату либо словами

Comment: Пояснения к вопросу напишите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Тут Вам нужно выбирать уже одно из трёх:

1. либо Вы используете стандартный элемент `type="date"`;
2. либо Вы убираете `type="date"` и "делаете всё сами";
3. либо Вы можете использовать jquery-ui datepicker (или какой-то другой плагин специально предназначенный для таких вещей).

HTML5 - прикольная штука. Жаль только он всё еще сильно ограничивает полёт нашей фантазии.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, за сегодня Вы мне во многом помогли